# CSS Layout Push Div Bottom

Tags: html, css

I've been trying different ways but couldn't achieve what I want.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1"></div>
  <div id="child-2"></div>
  <div id="child-3"></div>
</div>
```

So I have the `#parent` at `height: 100vh`.

`#child-1` should have `height: 100%` of parent.

`#child-2` and `#child-3` should have `width: 100%` and `height: auto` and they should be stacked on top of each other at position `bottom: 0`.

I've been trying to set parent relative and two childs absolute but the first child's height gets ignored.. I tried with `display flex` but first child's height is not 100% of parent.. I'm very confused how to do this.

Can someone help?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vhLuze86)

Comment: A jsFiddle would be helpful

Comment: can you make a picture to show your purpose.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhLuze86/ I had to do it with fixed positioning... which is not what I want. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: I guess that you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vhLuze86/3/ ? Not sure about pure CSS solution, but with little jquery (or pure JS, nevermind) code, you can achieve desired result?

Comment: @nevermind, thanks I was hoping no JS because then the bottom value for child2 is not responsive to layout.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first get the `bottom` value of `#child-2` dynamically as you said it should be on the top of `#child-3`.

You need to apply jQuery to get the height of `#child-3` dynamically and then applying the height value of `#child-3` to the `bottom` value of `child-2`, just like

```
#child-2 {
  bottom: height-of-child-3;
}
```

**Look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmYpaj)**

Or look at the snippet below:

```js
height_child_three = $('#child-3').height();

$('#child-2').css({
 position: 'absolute',
 bottom: height_child_three
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

#child-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

#child-2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #a0ea0e;
}

#child-3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #30e30e;
}

body { margin: 0; } /* A small reset */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-1">
    <strong>I'm child 1</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="child-2">
    <strong>I'm child 2</strong>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione deleniti voluptate commodi distinctio, repellendus qui, placeat laboriosam eligendi! Ducimus reiciendis officiis debitis placeat adipisci quae hic tempore vitae suscipit nemo.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam sed aliquid, laborum nisi quos excepturi hic! Molestias hic consectetur dolor! Perferendis iste, quisquam quaerat ab, odio ducimus! Odio, minima error?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="child-3">
    <strong>I'm child 3</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should have explained more clearly. For the `#child-2` and `#child-3` the height should be auto based on width of screen. I don't know how I can use `bottom` attribute for `#child-2` if I don't know the height of `#child-3`.

Comment: @cocacrave, "the height should be auto based on width of screen"? Could you explain, please? It seems you will have to use some javascript to calculate heights, if you didn't set it....

Comment: @cocacrave Oh! I think you are asking how to get the `bottom` value of `#child-2`? Ok! You can't find the value of `#child-2`. You have to use Javascript to get the value of each child and set them accordingly. Check the updated answer!

Comment: Ahh I see you have to use js. That makes sense. THANKS!! One thing though... I played around with your code but there's an issue where if you put some lorem on `#child-3` and resize the viewport `#child-2` stays the same bottom value. Does that mean I have to listen to viewport resize + check if height of `#child-3` equals bottom value of `#child-2` if not change bottom value?  Is there no way to do it in CSS?

Comment: @cocacrave Yes! to make it responsive you need to listen to the viewport resize and then again apply the properties. And you have to use JS again to make it happen. There is no way in CSS to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error voluptatum necessitatibus dolorem soluta laudantium cupiditate maiores neque, aliquid accusamus autem saepe tempora, itaque possimus, eaque deleniti odio atque enim omnis.</div>
  <div class="child-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, illo est dolor dolores placeat deleniti quae consequuntur eum ipsum blanditiis laboriosam quod repellendus fugit! Odio quis rem vel a dolores.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.child-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.child-3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

Here you can see a solution just using plain CSS. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNveVB?editors=1100)

Comment: Actually, after seeing the codepen, it's not what I was looking for.. I was scratching my head how the code worked but it wasn't what I thought it was. The two bottom divs should have been in view on top of child1. Thanks though.

Comment: Hi @cocacrave, a way for achieving this without modifying the HTML is to play with "flex" and "flex-direction" or "order" properties.